# $Ax = b$ and $Ax = 0$ solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having trouble classifying the solution set of the systems $Ax = b$ and $Ax = 0$.

Let A be an ($m \times n$) matrix.

**Case I:**

*For $Ax = 0$, the system has a unique solution (the trivial one) when A is invertible, and infinitely many solutions when A is not.*

- We can scratch off the "no solution" case because there is always the zero matrix solution correct?

**Case II:**

*For $Ax = b$, if A is invertible, then for all ($n \times 1$) vector b, the matrix equation has a unique solution given by $x = A^{-1}b$.
Else, there are two remaining cases: infinitely many solutions or no solutions.*

- How would I know which it is? Can we not tell until we have row reduced the augmented matrix?

Finally is the following true or false?

**If y and z are solutions of the system Ax = b then any linear combination of y and z is also a solution.**

My thoughts are that it is correct but I am not too sure.

Comment: Just a small part, I want to add. It may possible that $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix (also you have mentioned about it). So, $A^{-1}$ does not exist for those cases. But even for those cases also unique solution for $Ax=b$ can exist, if-

$1. \ b \in \mathbf{R}(A),$

$2. m \geq n, \text{ and } rank(A)=n.$

The solution is given as, $x= (A^T A)^{-1}A^T b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes, there is always the zero - vector solution $x = 0$

2) Yes, you need to compute the rank of the augmented matrix.

3) No. If $Ay = b$ and $Az=b$ then $$A(y+z) = Ay + Az = b + b = 2b \neq b$$

except the case when $b= 0$. If $b=0$ then it is true and that is why $Ker(A)$ is a vector space.

Is there a "certain" combination that works? Let's see:

$$A(\alpha y + \beta z) = \alpha Ay + \beta Az = (\alpha + \beta)b = b$$ and again, with $b \neq 0$ this implies $\alpha + \beta = 1$.

So you still have a solution provided that the "weights" sum up to $1$

Comment: Thanks, nice proof for the third. So it would be true for Ax = 0. Would changing the statement to "certain" linear combinations of y and z are also a solution (i.e 2x - y) make it true for Ax = b?

Comment: @kevin001 edited. Take a look :-)

Comment: So, I just notice an interesting thing from your proof that- "If $y$ and $z$ are solutions of the system $Ax = b$ then any affine combination of $y$ and $z$ is also a solution."

Comment: @Rajada nice :) what interesting thing did you notice?

Comment: The "affine" combination of $y$ and $z$ will be the solution of the $Ax=b$ problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case II, note  that in general, $A$ will not be invertible, as this requires $m=n$.

The condition for having solutions is the rank of the augmented matrix is equal to $\operatorname{rank}A$ (in all cases it is $\ge\operatorname{rank}A$). It is the case if $A$ has rank $m$, which implies $n\ge m$ and $A$ is *right*-invertible – in particular if $A$ is invertible.

Concerning the last question, the solution is not a subspace, but it is an *affine subspace*, which means any *weighted mean* of solutions is again a solution.